# React simple input field with conditional rendering problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements

I am reading a book "Pure React" by Dave Ceddia, below is a question I am getting stuck, I appreciate for any solution as simple as possible, thanks.

Question: Return the appropriate JSX from this component so that when username is undefined or null, it renders “Not logged in”. When username is a string, render “Hello, username

My answer:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM, { render } from 'react-dom';

function Greeting(){
  render(){
   let username = '';
   let greeting = '';

   if(typeof username == String){
    greeting = <span>Hello {username}</span>
   }else{
    greeting = <span>Not logged in</span>;
   }

   return (
    <div>
     <input type="text" value={username}/>
     {greeting}
    </div>
   )
  }
 }

ReactDOM.render(
  <Greeting/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: What's your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed [class component syntax with functional component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) syntax.

Below I rewrite your code to correct functional component using [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). Also, I use [inline If-Else conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator) `greeting` element.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Greeting(){
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
   
  let greeting = username 
    ? <span>Hello {username}</span>
    : <span>Not logged in</span>;
     
  return (
    <div>
     <input type="text" value={username} onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} />
     {greeting}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Greeting/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

- `username` is your component input, so you must pass it as prop. You could set a default value to it in the case this is not defined. Although you might have presented above for demonstration/test purposes
- Your component is not a class from the look of what you shared, this a functional component. Therefore, `render` class method doesn't apply here
- The question says "when username is undefined or null, it renders “Not logged in”", you should just follow what the question is saying by not reversing the logic on checking if `username` is a string

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM, { render } from 'react-dom';

function Greeting({ username = '' }) {
   let greeting;
   if (username === undefined || username === null) {
      greeting = (<span>Not logged in</span>);
   } else {
      greeting = (<span>Hello {username}</span>);
   }

   return (
    <div>
     <input type="text" value={username}/>
     {greeting}
    </div>
   )
  }
 }

ReactDOM.render(
  <Greeting username='' />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Hi your answer is the most simple one which is what I want, because I am not familiar with React syntax yet. However, I got 'greeting' is not defined  no-undef, could you please check how to correct it? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot type any word in the input field, please check,thanks.

Comment: You need to pass a callback to the input element in order to mutate your state and control your component, please read react [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

Comment: You are welcome! React hooks are rough to learn but I believe the new paradigm will make things easier to move with!

Answer (score 0):

You can define state such as username and make your greeting message dependent upon it on change.
I have created following sandbox to show the solution:

https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-browser-iohyt

Following is the component's JS code:

```
import React from "react";

export default function Greeting() {
  const [ username, setUserName ] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={username}
        onChange={evt => setUserName(evt.target.value)}
      />
      <span>{username ? `Hello ${username}`:"Not logged in"}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function Header() {
        let username = 'Username_here';
        let isValid;
        function validString(){
            if(typeof username === 'string'){
            return isValid=true;
            }
            else {
                return isValid=false;
            }
        }
        validString();
    
        return (
            <>
            <span>
                {isValid && 'Hello,' +  username}
                {!isValid && 'Not Logged In'}
            </span>
            </>
        );
    }
    
    export default Header;

At first I created a component header then just import this to app.js file.
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.